# How can I set identity to each cell in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, global-variables

I have a grouped UITable view as custom setting view. Each cell is a view with 3 UITextFields and some other UIViews.

When the cell is created I call a function

```
[cell initCell:indexPath.section withRow:indexPath.row];
```

And then the cell knows which configuration to display - this works fine.

My problem is that when the table is scrolled then the cell looses it's identity causing it to save the wrong settings.
I saved 
NSString* view;
NSString* row;

but it always have the last value, of the last cell presented (became sidplayed)

Maybe I have a missunderstanding about global parameters, or maybe about the cell reuse.
Please Advise,
Thanks

My cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if(indexPath.section==0)
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifierDate = @"SettingsCellPickDate";

    SettingsCellPickDate *cell = (SettingsCellPickDate *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierDate];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifierDate owner:self options:nil];

        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[SettingsCellPickDate class]]) 
            {
                cell = (SettingsCellPickDate *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    [cell initCell:indexPath.section withRow:indexPath.row];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;



    cell.frame = CGRectZero;

    return cell;
}


//tableView.rowHeight = 100;    
static NSString *CellIdentifierDate = @"SettingsCellValue";

SettingsCellValue *cell = (SettingsCellValue *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierDate];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifierDate owner:self options:nil];

    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[SettingsCellValue class]]) 
        {
            cell = (SettingsCellValue *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

[cell initCell:indexPath.section withRow:indexPath.row];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

cell.frame = CGRectZero;

return cell;

}
```

For example, the SettingsCellValue class looks like this (I change some texts and removed stuff that could suggest my app idea):

```
#import "SettingsCellValue.h"

@implementation SettingsCellValue
@synthesize defLabel1, defLabel2, defLabel3, defLabel4, text1, text2, text3, typeOfBar;

//@synthesize defLabel, valueField;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {
        // Initialization code
    }

    return self;
}

NSString *view;
NSString *bar;

-(void) initCell:(int)section withRow:(int)row
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger viewType = [defaults integerForKey:@"ScreenType"]; 

    bar = [self getBarAsText:section];
    view = [self getViewTypeAsText:viewType];

    //Update row 1
    defLabel1.text = @"Text1";
    text1.text = [defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/Caption", view, bar]];
    //Update row 2
    defLabel2.text = @"Text2";
    typeOfBar.selectedSegmentIndex = [defaults integerForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/Type", view, bar]];
}

- (NSString *) getBarAsText:(int)section
{
    switch (section) {
        case 1:
            return @"Ba1r";
            break;
        case 2:
            return @"Bar2";
            break;
        case 3:
            return @"Bar3";
            break;
        default:
            return @"Ba1r";
            break;
    }
}

- (NSString *) getViewTypeAsText:(int)viewType
{
    switch (viewType) {
        case 1:
            return @"viewType1";
            break;
            case 2:
                return @"viewType2";
                break;
            case 3:
                return @"viewType3";
                break;
            case 4:
                return @"viewType4";
                break;
        default:
            return @"viewType1";
            break;
    }
}

-(IBAction) editingDidEnded:(id) sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (sender == text1) {
        [defaults setObject:text1.text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/Caption", view, bar]];
    }


    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [ defLabel1, defLabel2, defLabel3, defLabel4, text1, text2, text3, typeOfBar release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: It would be helpful to se ur `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: You would best be served by reading up on MVC and perusing the tableview suite sample code. You're doing things so wrong you need to start over and change the way you're thinking. That's more than I want to help you with myself. Please learn what MVC is, what it's for, and that this is how the frameworks are designed and expected to be used. In addition, learn about cell reuse, how tableviews work, etc. There are many examples in the suite i reference in this comment. Best of luck.

Comment: What does initCell:withRow: look like?

Comment: It is a plain function that updates the text for the cell's lables.
It is also updating a local variable that I later use to update the right configurations. But from some reason this variable is allways set to the value of the last cell created.

I should emphesis that my cell reuse works fine. I checked the editingEnd function while the maximum number of cells is visible and I saw that when the function is called the variable value is set, as I said, to the last cell created value. Even though I'm on another instance, which means other global variabels right?

Comment: to see everything related to that variable could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your patient with me - sorry fot that.
added the code of the problematic cell type

Comment: u pass the int row to initCell:withRow:, but u dont use it. So if i understand ur code correctly, the cell only can change, if the section changes, not the row, that r actually represented by cells.

Comment: Because I needed the UIComponents of the table to be controlled from one place, I built a super custon cell and the table really is a grouped/sectioned table with each section containing only one row. This is why I stopped using the row param.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't tie a certain data-object to a certain cell-object, as this would break cell-reuse. While your code doesn't look totally wrong, your question's title points in the direction, that you haven't understood that yet.

One thing I noticed: You use `static NSString *CellIdentifierDate` twice. you should rename one.

Comment: First, thanks for the the top I changed the variable name, it also shouldn't say "Date". Someone once said Command+C, Command+V are your biggest enemy.

My cell reuse works great, my only problem is that a global variable of the cell is set to the value of the cell created last. Read what I wrote in the comment for the other answear.

Comment: As I pointed out — the code u posted doesnt look wrong. The error is elsewhere.

Comment: My problem is with the variable "NSString* bar" that from some reason is always set to the value of the last cell created/reused. It is set using -(void) initCell:(int)section withRow:(int)row